# curl error when upload to the webhost

Tags: php, json, curl

I am going to have a `php` that upload `json` to the web.

Here is my file to upload (located in my local drive)

**test.php**

```
$string = file_get_contents("results.json");

$ch = curl_init();
$post_values = array('json_data' => $string);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, '<dir path>/test1.php');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $post_values);
$data = curl_exec($ch);
if (!curl_errno($ch)) {
    echo 'Received raw data' . $data;
}
curl_close($ch);
?>
```

This is the code to get the posted json

**test1.php**

```
<?php

$data = json_decode($_POST['json_data'], true);

header('Content-type: text/json');

foreach ($data['queue'] as $queue) {
    echo "Wof = " . $queue['wof'];
    echo "Input Date = " . $queue['input_date'] . "<br />";
}
?>
```

Both code works well.

But when I upload **test1.php** to the web server, it means I send my `json` located in my computer to the server. I doesn't work.

No Error msg I get, only it does not show the data. only show `Received raw data`

My question is : **How to fix it?, is there something wrong with my code?**

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Have you changed CURLOPT_URL to your server URL? And why do you send 'Content-type: text/json' if it's not JSON anymore?

Comment: Yes, I have changed it, 
sorry, I don't quite understand about json and curl, why it is not json anymore?

Comment: Please elaborate on "it doesn't work" - what error messages do you get?

Comment: @Sieryuu: because in  test1.php you decoded your JSON.

Comment: Use `text/plain` on your **test1.php** would be better. But that may not be the point. I'll suggest you to `print_r($data)` (and other variables) in your **test1.php** to debug what happen on the server.

Comment: @RomanNewaza I removed the decoded, and it show the data, but how to show it like before, can I use `foreach`?

Comment: @RomanNewaza yeah, post for the answer